# Finding repeating patterns and their periods

Tags: autocorrelation, seasonality, pattern-recognition, fourier-transform

I have a list of user-generated events stored together with the time it occurred. FWIW, the average is 216 event per day and a total of approximately 800000 events.

My goal is simply to find the repeating patterns and their periods and how they evolve through time. I expect to find at least two patterns with a period of 24 hours, 7 days, and maybe a third with a period of 1 year. But the interesting thing would be, of course, if I find more patterns.

I tried to count the number of event per hour and use a Fourier transform or an autocorrelation on that *"signal"*, but none of those methods are completely satisfactory.

### Fourier Transform

My first thought was to aggregate the events per hour and plot a spectrogram from a short-term Fourier transform. Here is the result.

[image: Sort-term FFT of the events per day]

It works quite well, it shows a sharp line for 24 hours and some kind of line for 168 hours (7 days). But the major drawback is the period-resolution. It produce a very low resolution for large periods, and so much information for short periods that I any peak would be averaged out on the plot. If I try increase the blocksize to get a better precision for large periods, I would also increase the number of data points for short periods, which quickly become unmanageable in terms of CPU and memory needed to plot all that data.

### Autocorrelation

The second idea was to use an autocorrelation between a chunk and half of the chunk and only keep the values where there is a total overlap (called ["valid" mode in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)). This should show a high value for a lag equal to the period of a repeating pattern. Here is the result.

[image: Autocorrelation of the number of events per day]

With this, I only get integer periods (which is fine), but the plot doesn't show peaks as sharp as the Fourier transform does. And it doesn't really show that there is a pattern every 168 hours, which limit its usefulness.

### Other idea

I'm open to any suggestion about another method. Here is one that might just be a stupid random thought. Why not make a continuous model of the event occurence with a kernel density estimate for instance, take its (continuous) Fourier transform, and then discretize this as I want? Any opinion on that? Here is the [link to the math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948335/241838) question exploring this idea.

Another idea might be to use some kind of hierarchical autocorrelation. In order to sharpen the peaks and weaken the repeats.

Comment: You should add the [tag:seasonality] tag. What is your "signal", i.e. what would be the $x$ axis in a $x[t]$ plot? If you have expected periods, then generic fourier analysis is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I edited the question. Hope it's clearer. I indeed expect some periods to show up. I saw them by specifically looking for them. But I would want a more general method to show *all* the repeating patterns, even if they have a slightly changing period over the time.

Comment: For a given period $T$, you can fit a sinusoid with a simple linear least squares, so it is easy to refine a periodogram peak using scalar optimization to search over $T$ values in the coarse-periodogram bin. (Roughly as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_model), but I would definitely take advantage of the fact that the optimization is "separable".)